# Regex for certain words causes Spaces

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

For instance i'm trying to search this string

"this is a search LLC which can end up having spaces"

using the below regex, it's working fine but when I match and then remove it's causes a bunch of white spaces, so I want to limit the number the white space to just 1, how could I go about adding that?

`(?i)(?<=|^)LLC|end|having(?=|$)`

`this is a search LLC which can end up having spaces`

`this is a search   which can  up  spaces`

```
public static String removeValuesByRegex(String input, Pattern pattern, String replaceWith){
    String result;

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    return result = matcher.replaceAll(replaceWith).trim();
}
```

Then in my test class im doing

```
String keywords = 'LLC|end|Having';
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)(?<= |^)\'|' + keyWords + '\'|(?= |$)');

String stringResult = UtilString.removeValuesByRegex('This is a LLC and General Partnership Test ', pattern, '');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicate spacing, I recommend you call `normalizeSpace` on the output:

```
String result = MyClass.myMethod(input, pattern, '').normalizeSpace();
```

Note from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm):

> **normalizeSpace()**
>   Returns the current String with leading, trailing, and repeating white space characters removed.